# Huge fonts in Skype 5.1

Tags: skype

I have huge fonts in the messaging window, and there I can't find a configuration item to change it.

It's the new Skype 5.1 for Mac.

Why did this happen, and **how can I restore the fonts to their normal sizes?**

Comment: And what is the question here?

Comment: Why did this happen? i did not want those huge fonts. They were not there this morning. How do I get my old fonts back?

Comment: In the future, please leave the rant out of your question. We know you're frustrated, but isn't a great way to get your point across. Please take a look at the edit I've made and add any more info you think is relevant (screen caps may help). Thanks.

Comment: got you. you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having an application issue on Mac OS X, and it is not something that is expected behavior, a good first step is to quit the program, remove the user specific `.plist` files for that application, and then relaunch it. If regenerating the `.plists` doesn't work, it is probably time to reinstall Skype.

If this change is just a result of intended behavior (i.e. an update changed the way the program works), I recommend uninstalling and downloading a previous version to your liking.

http://mac.oldapps.com/skype.php